# Where can I find an Ethereum Gas Price chart on Ropsten testnet?

Tags: gas, testnets, ropsten, gas-price

For the main Ethereum blockchain, we can have access to the history of ETH gas price here : https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice

I would like to have access to something similar for the Ropsten testnet.

Comment: I don't think it does exist. It's a testnet, so no one really pays something

Answer (score 3):

Should be `https://ropsten.etherscan.io/chart/gasprice`, even though the chart looks a little weird.